# Ingress controller - proxy pass based on user agent

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to proxy_pass the traffic based on user-agent. Tried to use server-snippet / configuration-snippet for it, but ingress doesn't allow me. (Forbids to use proxy_pass in server-snippet and argues about duplicates in configuration-snippet)

I can't just use the "backend" as I have to dynamically pass the traffic myself based on user-agent.
Any chances I could do it? Not working configuration example below (without user-agent yet)

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress

spec:
  rules:
  - host: m-rm-qa.yadayadayada
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend-svc
          servicePort: 80
metadata:
  name: rm-frontend-ingress
  namespace: rm-qa
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      proxy_pass http://prerender-service:3000;
      rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
```

Comment: Are you considering use a standard nginx as a service instead nginx ingress?

Comment: hi @Федор Дао did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to reproduce your scenario using Nginx Ingress but without success using `server-snippet` and `configuration-snippet`.

I did some researches and see that `Nginx Plus` there's a snippet called `location-snippet` that should work. See [here.](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/#snippets-and-custom-templates)

Alternatively, I've created a custom Nginx deployment with a Service type `LoadBalancer` and created a `configMap` with a custom Nginx configuration, and it's works!

If you want to try, you need to create a `configMap` with your custom `default.conf` file, it's looks like this:

> I'm using the namespace: `default` for this example, but you can create a custom namespace if you want.

**nginx-custom-config.yaml:**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: custom-nginx-config
  namespace: default
data:
  default.conf: |
    upstream my-svc {
        server echo-svc.default.svc.cluster.local;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {

            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;

            if ($http_user_agent ~* "iPhone|iPad" ) {
                add_header X-Vendor "Apple";
                proxy_pass  http://my-svc;
            }
            if ($http_user_agent ~ Chrome ) {
                add_header X-Vendor "OpenSource";
                proxy_pass  http://my-svc;
            }

            proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
```

Apply to Kubernetes:

```
kubectl apply -f nginx-custom-config.yaml
```

- I've created `upstream` called `my-svc` pointing to my destination service `echo-svc.default.svc.cluster.local`.
- In my `location: /` there's a condition that matches the `User-agent`, in this case, if a request was made from a Apple device `"iPhone|iPad"` a header named `X-Vendor` with value `Apple` will be created and redirected the request to my destination service `my-svc`. The same will happen if the request was made from "Chrome", but the header will be `X-Vendor: "OpenSource"`.
- If the request was made from another browser, like firefox, curl etc... them the Nginx default page will be displayed.

After that you need to create a `deployment` of a Nginx image mounting our `configMap` as a file inside the containers, like this:

**custom-nginx-deployment.yaml:**

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: custom-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: custom-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: custom-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: custom-nginx
        image: nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - name: custom-nginx-config
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      volumes:
        - name: custom-nginx-config
          configMap:
            name: custom-nginx-config
```

`kubectl apply -f custom-nginx-deployment.yaml`

And finally, creating a `LoadBalancer` Service to received the requests:

**custom-nginx-svc.yaml:**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: custom-nginx-svc
  labels:
    app: custom-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: custom-nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

`kubectl apply -f custom-nginx-svc.yaml`

You can check if the container and service was successfully deployed using the commands:

```
kubectl get pods -l app=custom-nginx
kubectl get svc -l app=custom-nginx
```

Hope that helps!